# Resizing window after action is done

Tags: java, swing

Here's description of my problem (in one picture!): [image]

I would like to know:

1.) Why this is happening (I have even tried to `setMaximumSize()`, `setPreferredSize()`, `setMinimumSize()`!)?

2.) How I should resolve this? (I used `GridLayout`. It may or may not be super effective)

This is the setup code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class IntroScreen extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{   
    private boolean sandboxed = true;
    private final String SELECTION = "selection", CLEAN = "clean";

    private JPanel container;
    private DirectorySelectionPanel selectionPanel;
    private DirectoryCleanerPanel cleanerPanel;
    public IntroScreen()
    {
        super("Directory Cleaner");
        add((container = setupContent()));
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, this.getSize());
    }

    private JPanel setupContent()
    {

        JPanel content = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
        this.selectionPanel = new DirectorySelectionPanel(this.sandboxed);
        this.selectionPanel.getButton().addActionListener(this);
        content.add(this.selectionPanel, this.SELECTION);
        this.cleanerPanel = new DirectoryCleanerPanel(false);
        content.add(this.cleanerPanel, this.CLEAN);
        return content;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        // get the source of the event
        Object source = event.getSource();
        // if it was the selectionPanel's button
        if (source.equals(this.selectionPanel.getButton()))
        {
            if (this.selectionPanel.validateSelections())
            {
                System.out.println("Test line");
                ((CardLayout)this.container.getLayout()).show(this.container, this.CLEAN);
                // must figure out the correct size for this
                // TODO: Find a way to force the size of this to be around 450-by-90 pixels
                this.setSize(450,90);
            }
        }
        // otherwise
        else
        {
            // show the selectionPanel
            this.setSize(312,253);  // revert back to the original size
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new IntroScreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `setSize`, use `pack`.  In fact, I'd avoid changing the size at all and just let `CardLayout` and `pack` figure it out from the start

Comment: So, replace `this.setSize(mySize);` with `pack();`?

Comment: If so, it didn't work; /* it was the first thing I tried */

Comment: Shame, works fine for me, consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: This is how I set it up: http://imgur.com/ZiMG0Ns

By the way, `pack()` put the size closer to the size of the original size than to what I had (width: 306, height: 215)

Comment: The original size is probably what you need.  Stop "guessing" at what you think the size of the window should be and let the API do it for you, it does a better job.  Also, we don't screen shots of your code, we want code which can be copy and pasted into a IDE, compiled and run, so we debug it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92928/discussion-between-mike-warren-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: *"This is the setup code:"*  OK.. but without a `main(String[])` method to put it on-screen, it is not a [mcve] as mentioned by @MadProgrammer.  Voting to close.

Comment: @AndrewThompson fixed it